# Maven Incremental Compilation under Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've recently converted a big (and ugly) legacy project to Maven. It is a really really huge project (~2.7M lines of code, and a nice mix of java, jsp, js, and even VBS scripts) and is not well structured. Everything is located under a single Maven artifact (and thus a single Eclipse project).

Even with that bad structure, it used to be less or more manageable from Eclipse (even if a bit slow), but now, since it is Mavenized, every single change made to source code triggers an almost full rebuild of the code base (and 2.7M LoC take something like 10 minutes to finish), which is really unusable on a daily basis.

I've found the following bug report related to maven-compiler-plugin, unable to have an incremental compilation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205, and I'm quite confident that this is the root of our performance issues.

Have you any workaround? Do you know of a maven-compiler-plugin version not impacted with that issue? Or a setting in Eclipse which could help? Any other idea?

Thanks

Comment: which version of the maven compiler plugin are you using?

Comment: We are using 3.3 (the latest). The behavior has been seen with 3.0 as well. I'm trying to use 2.5.1 to see if it helps

Comment: Are you really saying a single artifact contains the whole code? If so...Than this the real problem...First try to refactor out modules...this will help...not only reduce build times it will also make changes simpler...

Comment: as I said, this is legacy code and it actually has more critical weakness than the project layout... written originaly 15 years ago with almost every anti-pattern. Refactor is not an option. No unit testing. Dozens of customers. End of life product, which will be rewritten as soon as we get enough budget...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incremental compiler in Eclipse (ecj, used by the JDT) totally overrides the compiler used by command line Maven builds. Any maven-compiler-plugin or javac issue should be discarded as irrelevant. I would expect m2e/Maven to have no significant impact on a single project workspace, as big as it is. Obviously since you're seeing the opposite behavior, something is apparently slowing down the Maven builder.

Since you use jsp and js files, my guess this is a war project. If you're using the Eclipse Java EE distribution, one thing you can try is to disable the m2e-wtp integration, see if it makes any difference. Go to Preferences > Maven > Java EE Integration and uncheck Enable Java EE Configuration.

If that doesn't help (or doesn't apply to your set up), another thing you could try would be to disable Maven resource processing during incremental builds. In your pom.xml, try adding:

```
    <profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>m2e</id>
    <!-- This profile is only activated when building in Eclipse with m2e -->
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>m2e.version</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
            only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <groupId>
                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                      </groupId>
                      <artifactId>
                        maven-resources-plugin
                      </artifactId>
                      <versionRange>
                        [1.0,)
                      </versionRange>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                      <ignore></ignore>
                    </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
                </pluginExecutions>
              </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

There's a chance it might break something else, but at least that should help determine whether resource processing is the culprit here.

Anything else will require a deeper analysis, I suggest you open a ticket to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=M2E

Comment: it seems that you are absolutely right, and disabling resources processing helped a lot. My guess was that it was stuck on compiling, but it was in fact copying our thousands js&jsp files. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Disable automatic build](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_turn_off_autobuilding_of_Java_code%3F) is the only option you have. Just build when you are interested in the artifacts.

You did not say what [goals you are calling maven with](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html). Maybe it would already be enough if you do not run all tests using `-DskipTests` (or even not compile them by using `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`), or if not willing to skip those introduce profiles to run just the necessary tests.

Since you are telling it's a legacy project I suspect that changing the project structure into a multi-module maven project is out of scope. You can then try if you can speed up using [parallel builds](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) (using `-T 4` (4 threads) or `-T 2C` (2 threads per core).

Comment: The goals I'm using are the one used by the m2e plugin, which I suspect to be "mvn compile" (thus, most of time is spent in maven-compiler-plugin). I'm afraid that disabling automatic build (even if working) will be hard to accept by the team. I really need to have incremental build enabled.

Skipping tests compilation may of course help a bit, I will give a look

Comment: Yes it would be very difficult to extract modules at the moment. I will investigate if multi-threading the compilation will help

Comment: Using `-T ...`  will not help in this cause it's a single module...`-T ...`  is based on module parallelisation (in a multi module build)...and not of parallelisation of the compiler which will not really work...